# rails join query between two tables with similar field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : CompanyAccount
  has_many : CompanyContact
end

class CompanyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : Company
end

class CompanyAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : Company
end
```

As both the CompanyAccount and CompanyContact models belong to the Company model, they have a similar "company_id" field. I have retrieved some Accounts through a query:

```
@CompanyAccounts = CompanyAccount.where.not(balance:nil)
```

Now, using the common company_id field I am trying to retrieve all the data from my CompanyContacts table that belong to the same Company associated with the CompanyAccounts I queried above (in other words, I am trying to get the rows which have the same company_id). I have made several attempts using "joins" but everything failed so far. Could anyone give me what would be the appropriate syntax in this context? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, please pay attention to proper Ruby naming conventions. Ruby classes and modules should use `CamelCase` while symbols, methods, and variables should all use `snake_case`. Given this, I would re-write your models as follows

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: company_accounts
  has_many: company_contacts
end

class CompanyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: company
end

class CompanyAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: company
end
```

Now, onto your question. I would use `includes` to eager load the associated company and it's associated contacts. For example

```
@company_accounts = CompanyAccount.includes(company: :company_contacts).where.not(balance: nil)
```

What this will do is for each company account with a balance, it will load it's associated company and the company's associated contacts into memory so that you can access it

```
@company_accounts.each do |account|
  # access to the company
  account.company

  # access to the company's contacts
  account.company.contacts
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and thanks for the naming convention comment. In the second case (#access to the company's contacts), I do not retrieve an object though but a collection for which I cannot call the attribute directly. Is the best option to build an array to retrieve the attribute (e.g. name) of account.company.contacts?

Comment: So you would like to retrieve an array of contact names? You could do `account.company.contacts.map(&:name)`.